# In BIRT, when editing line charts, how do you plot multiple series of the same data?

Tags: eclipse, birt

I work with the BIRT plugin for Eclipse and have a data set for a printing system consisting of the following entries:

Date date
NumberOfJobs int8
UserName text

I want to plot the NumberOfJobs in a given time period for each UserName (so if I have 5 distinct user names, I should have 5 series in the chart). I know how to plot the NumberOfJobs for all users, but not for each one separately. Is it possible to do that? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the chart wizard, on the Data Tab, there is a "group by" selector on the right-hand side.  Drag your Username field from the data summary at the bottom over to the grouping control.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select Chart TYpe -> Multiple Y Axis = Secondar

Comment: I have same kind of data and want to draw different line chart but using this kind of grouping not resolve my problem. Can someone help me out i have a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39329664/how-to-create-line-chart-from-birt-chat-plugin-in-eclipse