# How to create Line chart from birt chat plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, report, birt

I am using eclipse brit plugin to generate a line chart. Basically i want to create a report to present a mobile battery usage in given time range. Here is sample data where observationtime is dynamic based on user selected range:

I want to draw a line chart of per device but unable to find any configuration to draw different charts per device on same report page. Can someone help me on this ?

------------------------Update configuration and result-----------------

[image]

[image]

------------ after using list -----------
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution basically we need to add a table and then add grouping inside tablet on desired field and then in footer need to add a chart and it should get the values from container rather than directly from Data set.

Answer (score 0):

I the "Select Data" tab of your chart, select the time for the Category (X) Axis, The battery usage for the Value (Y) Axis an the device name for "Optional Y Series Grouping" (on the right side of the chart).

Comment: Thanks you for sharing this info.  I already have same changes but still when i run a report it showing all the devices on same line chart. Can you please tell me where i made mistake in report configuration.

Comment: oh you want one chart per device, not one Line per Device inside the same chart. I am not sure if this is possible in a dynamic way. You have to add one chart Item for every device to your report and just transfer the data of one device to display in the chart.

Comment: I have a little luck as i have created a list on a data set and then added a chart inside the list i can see now multiple charts. It is still showing same device in all charts so doing further investigating that how i can show them for each device. New picture added in question